# Will this random double generator work?

Tags: language-agnostic, random, floating-point, double, probability

Intuitively one might write a random double generator as follows:

```
double randDouble(double lowerBound, double upperBound)
{
    double range = upperBound - lowerBound;
    return lowerBound + range * rand();
}
```

**Suppose we assume that `rand()` returns an evenly distributed pseudorandom double on the interval [0, 1).**

Is this method guaranteed to return a random double within [lowerBound, upperBound) with a uniform probability distribution?  I'm specifically interested in whether the nature of floating point calculations might cause spikes or dips in the final distribution for some ranges.

Comment: Best if you read this wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#.22True.22_random_numbers_vs._pseudorandom_numbers) first as this is a "difficult" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, rand() generates **pseudo-random** numbers and not truly random. Thus, I will assume you are asking if your function generates pseudo-random numbers within the specified range.

Second, like Oli Charlesworth said, many rand implementations return a number between 0 and RAND_MAX, where RAND_MAX is the largest possible value it can take. In these cases, you can obtain a value in [0, 1) with

```
double r = rand()/((double)RAND_MAX+1);
```

the `+1` is there so that r can't be 1.

Other languages have a rand that returns a value between 0 and 1, in which case you don't need to do the above division. Either way, it turns out that your function returns a decent approximation of a random distribution. See the following link for more details: http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/rand.html Note that this link gives you slightly different functions which they claim work a bit better, but the one you have probably works good enough.

Answer (score 2):

If your upper and lower bounds are adjacent powers of two, then your resulting distribution will be as good as the one you get from `rand()`, since you're effectively just altering the exponent of what `rand()` gives you, without altering the mantissa.

If you want to stretch the range to cover more than one power of two, then there will be valid floating point numbers in the lower half of your range that will never be generated by your method. (You're effectively shifting one or more bits of the mantissa into the exponent, leaving the least significant bit(s) of the mantissa as non-random.)

If you use the method on a more general range (such that the mantissa is modified by the calculation), then you also run in to the same non-uniformity you get when trying to convert convert a random integer to a random integer modulo *n* without using rejection sampling.

Any correct method for generating a uniform distribution of floating point numbers has to take in to account that the interval of real numbers that round to any given floating point number is not always the same width. In the lower part of a range, floating point numbers will be more dense, so each individual floating point number in that part of the range should be selected less often than the larger numbers.

Comment: By this definition of correctness, and from what I've seen out in the wild, no one's implementation of generating uniform random doubles within a range is correct. :(

Comment: That's because it doesn't make much of a difference for most uses, and because doing it properly may require a lot more random bits (which was expensive until hardware RNGs started showing up in mainstream CPUs). But it's simple enough to implement: generate a fixed-point random number wide enough to cover the dynamic range you're sampling from, reject it if it isn't within your exact bounds, and then convert to floating-point. But you might end up needing a kilobit or two of random data if you're sampling from the entire range of a double-precision number.

Answer (score 1):

Well, no.  `rand()` returns a number between 0 and `RAND_MAX`; this quantisation will leave big holes in your distribution; in fact, almost all floating-point values in-between `lowerBound` and `upperBound` will never be selected.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply the specific C implementation of rand(), I was thinking a function more like Java's Math.random().  I've clarified that in the question.

Comment: @donnyton: Ah, ok.  Even so, this will still leave values that will never be selected.